# Comparing file creation date

Tags: python

I am trying to archive old files based on creation date. I have data starting from 12-17-2010 so i am setting this as base date and incrementing from there. Here is my code

```
import os, time, tarfile
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
import datetime

path = "/home/appins/.scripts/test/"
count = 0
set_date = '2010-12-17'
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(set_date, '%Y-%m-%d')

while (count < 2):
    date += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    tar_file = "nas_archive_"+date.strftime('%m-%d-%y')+".tgz"
    log_file = "archive_log_"+date.strftime('%m-%d-%y')
    fcount = 0
    f = open(log_file,'ab+')
    #print date.strftime('%m-%d-%y')
    for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            file = os.path.join(root,file)
            file = os.path.join(path, file)
            filecreation = os.path.getctime(file)
            print datetime.fromtimestamp(filecreation)," File Creation Date"
            print date.strftime('%m-%d-%y')," Base Date"
            if filecreation == date:
                tar.add(file)
                f.write(file + '\n')
                print file," is of matching date"
                fcount = fcount + 1
    f.close()
    count += 1
```

filecreation variable is getting float value. How can I use it to compare with my base date?

Comment: For the record, `ctime` is not file creation date...

Comment: `count < 2` ... this will only compare two days.

Comment: yes. I am starting from small set first. If code starts working i will increase further.

Comment: Only do os.walk() once and create a list of (date, filename) pairs. Then you can sort that list and run through the entries without turning your hard disk to dust. (hyperbole there, its cached, but still...).

Comment: And since I'm being naggy, consider using `'%Y-%m-%d'` for your file names so that they are easy to sort if you want to view them later.

Comment: since application is writing data in %m-%d-%y format I have to stick to it. I will evaluate os.walk() option.

Comment: @tdelaney I have used os.walk and created list of tuples which contains filename and creation date. I am planning to take date in separate list and compare it with original list to create date based archive. Is there other easy way you can recommend or this will work?

Comment: @user2501825 - in linux, ctime is metadata change time, not creation time. A chmod will change it. But generally, it should work. Since you want to reference by filename, consider a dict with filename as key and a tuple/list/class as value. That makes the file lookup much faster than scanning the list. Some people collect size, mtime and even a hash of the file.

Answer (score 1):

```
timestamp = datetime.mktime(date.timetuple())
```

The 'timestamp' will contain a timestamp comparable to values returned by getctime. Regarding the comment under the question: on Windows getctime returns creation time, on UNIXes modification time (http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/os.path.html).

EDIT (regarding questions in comment):

1) mktime is present in Python 2.x: http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.mktime

2) [Get file creation time with Python on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408272/get-file-creation-time-with-python-on-linux)

EDIT2:

Obviously this is stupid, and one should proceed as suggested by tdelaney below:

```
date.fromtimestamp(filecreation)
```

and compare dates, not timestamps. I wasn't looking at what the algorithm was actually doing :)

Comment: is it applicable to python 2.6 also? On unix which one shall I use to get creation date?

Comment: I think you want to do the opposite - convert ctime into a date object. If you compare timestamp to ctime, you'll only get a match if its the same microsecond (unlikely). If you convert ctime to date, you'll match for anything in the same day.

Comment: Yes that is what i am looking for. Is there a way I can achieve that? filecreation variable is containing float value so if I can convert that to date then I can compare it with my base date.

Comment: First, don't use 'date' as a variable... it masks the date class from datetime. Then, just do `my_date = date.fromtimestamp(filecreation)`. Or, since you are using formatted strings anyway, convert it to a string `my_date = date.fromtimestamp(filecreation).strftime('%m-%d-%y')`.