# In Python how do I search for files created in the past 24 hours?

Tags: python, python-datetime

I am new to python and I want to find all files in a directory that have been created within the past 24 hours.  How do I filter the files that were created in 24 hour window.

This code will be used in Python 2.7 on Windows computer.

Comment: For what platform? See the comment under this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python).

Comment: What code do you have sofar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the stat of the file then check if its less then 24 hours...
You will need to do loop/recreation...

```
import os
import time
st = os.stat("test.py")
ctime = st.st_ctime
print time.time() - ctime/3600  # hours
    if mtime<24:
       print mtime
```

Comment: Note that this will only work on Windows. On Linux, `ctime` gives you the time of the most recent metadata change. [Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html).

Comment: Just google file creations date Linux Python

Comment: It clearly says in the docs that `st_ctime` does not refer to the creation time on Linux systems. If you google it, you will find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408272/get-file-creation-time-with-python-on-linux) which confirms it.

Comment: There is however a `st_birthtime` attribute but it's not available on all platforms.

Comment: Thanks, the solution works great!

Comment: @Chris mark as answered please! (and you can up vote if you want to be really nice...)